# use internal class in public method

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

hi I'm creating a library. I have a model class that is internal accessible and a method that is public.

I know that because of the level of access, internal access cannot be used in public

If I make model class access public, When the user uses the library, he has access to both the method and the model class
I want the user to have access to the method only

```
 public class GithubReleaseModel
        {
            public bool IsExistNewVersion { get; set; }
            public string Url { get; set; }
            public string Changelog { get; set; }
            public string Version { get; set; }
            public string DownloadUrl { get; set; }
            public string Size { get; set; }
            public bool IsPreRelease { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
            public DateTime PublishedAt { get; set; }
        }

 public static GithubReleaseModel IsNewVersionExistGithub(string Username, string Repository)
        {
            var model = new GithubReleaseModel();
            ...
            return model;
        }
```

Comment: In order to access a public method, the caller must also be able to access the class. If the caller is external and the class is internal, the caller cannot access the class's public methods directly. However, as a workaround, you could create a separate public wrapper class that will call the public method on the internal class.

Comment: Alternatively, consider creating a public interface, with the internal class inheriting from the interface.

Comment: What you are saying is quite contradictory. Your public method can't return an internal class, because if it did, there's no point for `internal` anymore. I can just access the class via your method. Maybe you just want a `internal` constructor?

Comment: By the way, you should consider renaming the method, without reading documentation most users would assume `IsNewVersionExistGithub` will return a `bool` value (is exist: yes/no).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want outside user not to be able to change properties, make the setters internal:

```
public bool IsExistNewVersion { get; internal set; }
```

This way everyone can read, but you can only write from inside the assembly (your library).

## EDIT

If you don't want users of your library to create an instance of your class, limit access to the constructor:

```
    public class GithubReleaseModel
    {

        internal GithubReleaseModel()
        {
            // internal constructor 
        }

        public bool IsExistNewVersion { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Changelog { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string DownloadUrl { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public bool IsPreRelease { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishedAt { get; set; }
    }

    public static GithubReleaseModel IsNewVersionExistGithub(string Username, string Repository)
    {
        var model = new GithubReleaseModel();
        ...
        return model;
    }
```

This way you can create and return your model just as you did already, but if someone from outside wants to create a `new GithubReleaseModel()` he gets an access violation.

Comment: @hadikhodabandeh So what exactly do you want? See my edit, maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is that you don't want the consumer of the library to instantiate your model, you can do make the constructor `private` or `internal`.

Example:

```
public class GithubReleaseModel
{
  private GithubReleaseModel()
  {
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i cant use  `public bool IsExistNewVersion { get; set; }` in private method that you say

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface with the methods the consumer method can call. Your implementation class can stay `internal` that way without exposing anything.

```
public interface IGithubReleaseModel {
    int DoSomethingYouWant();
}

internal class GithubReleaseModel : IGithubReleaseModel {
    public int DoSomethingYouWant() {
        return 42;
    }
}

public static IGithubReleaseModel IsNewVersionExistGithub(string Username, string Repository)
{
    var model = new GithubReleaseModel();
    ...
    return model;
}
```